# Django admin showing a white box instead of toggle theme icon

Tags: python, django

As I open Django admin page, a wide white box appears instead of the theme icon (using Django 4.2.1).

[image: admin page as appears on production]

While testing on Docker container, everything seems ok.

[image: admin page while testing on Docker container]

I have been looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#theming-support) on overriding admin/base.html, but I'm not sure this is the issue.

Checking the log after deployment (on EC cloud), nothing comes to my attention.

I am letting serve the static content by nginx (1.23).

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Overall, all static files are working properly on the rest of the site.

I tried inspecting the element `<button class="theme-toggle">`. Nothing anomalous.

Everything looks *normal* to me. Apart from this, production looks identical to the Docker container.

Answer (score 8):

In my case CTRL+F5 did the job .

Comment: Hence, you mean it is a browser issue and not a server issue?For those who wonder: CTRL+F5 is a hard refresh (skip cache) on your browser (CMD+R for Mac).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Just run

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear
```

Please note the `--clear` flag.

Comment: Maybe you need the Ctrl-F5 trick too after that if you use the same browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after updating to Django 4.2.1. Installing Django 4.2.0 instead fixed the toggle-theme issue and the (in my case unwanted) header "skip to main content" disappeared as well.

Comment: Indeed this showed up after upgrading to Django 4.2.1 along with a couple of other issues - solved by downgrading. I'm not a real fan of downgrading, though.

Comment: is downgrading the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to clear your browser cache and refresh the page after running *collectstatic*, that did it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is downgrading the only solution?

Comment: No downgrading is not needed. Run collectstatic again and clear your browser cache or force refesh, then it works.

Comment: doesn't work for me, the last comment I wrote was meant to be for the other answer, but what version do you use?

Comment: Ah I see... I'm running version 4.2.1 on three different servers. You may also try restarting your application server (I'm using Passenger and may have restarted it after running collectstatic).

Answer (score 1):

I just did a fresh

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

a reload and it worked

In my case the bug appeared bcz I was using static/ from previous version of django

Answer (score 0):

A hard refresh seems to work (ctrl+shift+r on Brave) for django=4.2.3.

This problem has never arisen in my previous django projects, do you feel using the `django-tailwind` package is the cause of this? Is anyone else facing this issue with `django-tailwind` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

1. python manage.py collectstatic - did not work for me
2. python manage.py collectstatic --clear - did not work for me
3. Downgrading from 4.2.4 to lower - did not work for me
4. Hard refresh browser - did not work for me
5. Clear cache - did not work for me

What worked for me since I have CloudFront to invalidate entire admin CSS folder, you can do it via AWS CLI or AWS Management Console:
Object path: /static/admin/css/*

Answer (score 0):

This file is the issue:

> admin/css/dark_mode.css

It should contain this line:

> html[data-theme="dark"]

If not, it's an older version.

All sorts of caching mechanism can make this page to appear like this, so it's best to know exactly what to look for to not have to blindly run a bunch of commands.

That being said, the problem I had that none of the answers helped me, was that I was running "collectstatic" outside of the virtual environment, so without raising an error, an older version of Django was mistakenly gathering the static files. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i delete the admin folder from staticfiles and re ran the

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```