# getting weird login page for django adming

Tags: django, django-admin, django-login

I am getting this weird login page for **Django admin** after deploying on server. In my local project everything is looking fine. I checked already if there is any css failing but everything seems fine. if anyone have any idea about this please help me to get rid of it.
[image]

Comment: check these answers.
[Django admin showing a white box instead of toggle theme icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199404/django-admin-showing-a-white-box-instead-of-toggle-theme-icon)

Comment: thank you @a.akbarnejad yes it worked what is suggested in the answer.